# constructor Book in class Book cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, abstract, superclass

in main

```
Book new_novel=new MyBook(title,author,p);
```

---

#### Abstract Class:

```
abstract class Book 
{

    Book(String t,String a){
       title=t;
       author=a;
    }
}
```

---

#### Inherited Class:

```
class MyBook extends Book{

    MyBook(String t,String a,int p){
        t= super.title;
        a = super.author;
        price = p;
    }         

}
```

Comment: Please go through the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) about how and what to ask here. From your code, you seem to be just beginning your journey with Java and object oriented programming - please go through a few tutorials. It will go a long way.

Comment: First of all ,you can't define object of type Book because Book is abstract

Comment: Ya, but it's just a reference. Object is of type MyBook . @coder

Comment: Seems you have right .Also you don't have fields title and author in class Book so how you use them in constructor???

Comment: String title;
String author; ya this 2 lines are there .

Comment: your code is simply invalid invalid. You have missing fields and you cannot call `super.<field>` in java.

Comment: Just an FYI, id call super(title,author); in the MyBook constructor instead of setting the values directly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user ppeterka suggested in the comments, some Java tutorials would do you wonders. Here's a great place to start: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

However, here's a little help:

You need to define fields in `Book` and `MyBook`.
For example:

```
public class Book {

    private String title;
    private String author;
    ...
}
```

As for the constructor, since `MyBook` extends `Book`, `MyBook`'s constructor can call `Book`'s constructor like this:

```
MyBook(String t,String a,int p){
    super(t, a); // Calls Book(title, author)
    price = p;
}
```

As an aside, user coder's statement that

> you can't define object of type Book because Book is abstract

is false. Your code `Book new_novel=new MyBook(title,author,p);` is a perfectly good line of code assuming you've defined `title` `author` and `p` already.

I hope you enjoy learing Java!

Comment: First of all thank you for the Explanation, i got it now. And of course i m enjoying java though i am from C background and directly i started java without the knowledge of C++ so it was trickier for me but now i am comfortable by doing some this kinds of codes .